# SQLAlchemy/psycopg2: JSONB columns are being returned as strings instead of dicts Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2, jsonb

If I have a table with a JSONB column, using SQLAlchemy engines to run a direct "execute" query (engine.execute, session.execute, etc.) returns strings for the JSONB instead of dicts.

I'm using the latest SQLAlchemy, what's going on?

Answer (score 4):

AHA! Your (my) problem is almost certainly due to a *PSYCOPG2* problem.

Versions before 2.5.4 returned strings instead of dicts for JSONB columns.

[Please see this link from the psycopg2 FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#faq-jsonb-adapt)

Comment: Oh, you can accept your own answers? That sure is egosticial! 